# Send value from button to textbox

Tags: php, html

im making a basic calculartor with PHP to send to my techer i have the basic html and php codes in the same file but i cant find the way to send the number from any button to the text to make a bigger number, like windows calc, if i introduce the number from my keyboard it ok and works but i dont know how can send the value from the buttton
this is the code

```
<html> 

 <head> 

  <title>Calculadora Basica</title> 
 </head> 

 <body> 
  <div align="center"> 
    <center> 
      <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>
      <table border="0" cellspacing="1" width="304" height="139"> 
        <tr> 
          <td width="292" align="center" height="39"> 
            <h3> Calculadora Basica</h3> 
          </td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
          <td width="292" align="center" height="23"> 
            <input type="text" name="num1" size="10"><br>    
            <input type="text" name="num2" size="10"></td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
          <td width="292" align="center" height="24"> 
            <input type="submit" value="+" name="operac"> 
            <input type="submit" value="-" name="operac"> 
            <input type="submit" value="*" name="operac"> 
            <input type="submit" value="/" name="operac"><br> 
            <input type="submit" value="^2" name="operac"> 
            <input type="submit" value="^3" name="operac"> 
            <input type="submit" value="Raiz" name="operac">  
            <input type="submit" value="%" name="operac"><br> 
            <input type="button" value="1" name="1">
            <input type="button" value="2" name="2">
            <input type="button" value="3" name="3"><br> 
            <input type="button" value="4" name="4">
            <input type="button" value="5" name="5">
            <input type="button" value="6" name="6"><br> 
            <input type="button" value="7" name="7">
            <input type="button" value="8" name="8">
            <input type="button" value="9" name="9">
            <input type="button" value="0" name="0">
          </td> 
        </tr> 

        <?php 
            $operac = $_POST['operac'];
            $num1 = doubleval($_POST['num1']);
            $num2 = doubleval($_POST['num2']);

            switch($operac) {
                case "+": $resultado = "{$num1} + {$num2} = ". strval($num1+$num2); break;
                case "*": $resultado = "{$num1} * {$num2} = " . $num1*$num2; break;
                case "/": $resultado = "{$num1} / {$num2} = " . $num1/$num2; break;
                case "-": $resultado = "{$num1} - {$num2} = " . strval($num1-$num2); break;
                case "Raiz": $resultado = "Raiz({$num1}) = " . sqrt($num1); break;
                case "^2": $resultado = "{$num1}^2 = " . $num1*$num1; break;
                case "^3": $resultado = "{$num1}^3 = " . $num1*$num1*$num1; break;
              case "%": $resultado = "{$num2}% de {$num1} = " . (($num2 * 100) / $num1); break;
            }
        ?> 

        <tr> 
          <td width="292" align="center" height="19"><br>
          <b>Resultado: <?php echo $resultado; ?></b></td> 
        </tr>      
      </table> 
     </form> 
   </center> 
  </div> 
</body> 

</html>
```

Comment: text to make a bigger number, mean ?

Comment: if i press the buttons 1,3,5,0 the num1 must get the value of 1350 same for the num2

Comment: This is not that hard to do, except one thing - how will the form know which input box to put the number into?  You have two separate inputs, and when the user clicks a number button, there's no way to know which box they mean for the number to go into. We can't use the current focus, since as soon as the user clicks a button the focus moves to the button itself... If you reworked it to use a single input box, like a real calculator, it would be much easier to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to update your html code little bit as follows to store clicked number button's value into textbox. Here, I stored that value in both textboxes. 
I replaced code little bit  of textbox, number's button and added one javascript function instead all code is as it is. 
Please, give one look.

Textboxes:

```
<tr>
<td width="292" align="center" height="23"> 
<input type="text" name="num1" id="num1" value="" size="10">
<input type="text" name="num2" id="num2" value="" size="10"></td> 
</tr>
```

Buttons:

```
<input type="button" onclick="storeNumber(this)" value="1" name="1">
<input type="button" onclick="storeNumber(this)" value="2" name="2">
<input type="button" onclick="storeNumber(this)" value="3" name="3"><br> 
<input type="button" onclick="storeNumber(this)" value="4" name="4">
<input type="button" onclick="storeNumber(this)" value="5" name="5">
<input type="button" onclick="storeNumber(this)" value="6" name="6"><br> 
<input type="button" onclick="storeNumber(this)" value="7" name="7">
<input type="button" onclick="storeNumber(this)" value="8" name="8">
<input type="button" onclick="storeNumber(this)" value="9" name="9">
<input type="button" onclick="storeNumber(this)" value="0" name="0">
```

Call Javascript function in head tag

```
<script language='javascript'>
function storeNumber( obj )
{       
var previousVal = document.getElementById("num1").value;
previousVal = previousVal + obj.value;
document.getElementById("num1").value = previousVal;
document.getElementById("num2").value = previousVal;
 }  
 </script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: tks mohini, i do some like it but a make a greater changes on my textbox, add one more for the operator and more scripts